# ErrorException Uninitialized string offset: 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have a purchase orders form, and on the form there are multiple identical fields, like in this picture below. I can store this form with 1 or 2 discount with 1 or 2 products, but when i store this form with "3 discount with 3 different products" i got this notice error ***Uninitialized string offset: 1***
[image: form po]

**Notice:**

> ErrorException
> **Uninitialized string offset: 1**

[image: Error Msg]

**Structure table:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I changed my loop like below, I really did not understand where was the problem, but this was a suggestion to use like this from someone. so my problem solved.

```
 foreach ($request->input('category_id') as $item => $value) {
     $orderDetail = new orderDetail();
     $orderDetail ->id= $request->id;
     $orderDetail ->supplier_id= $request->supplier_id[$item];
    .
    .
    .
     $orderDetail ->status = 0;

     $orderDetail ->save();
}
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: The problem was on the `$orderDetail->discount_amount   = $request->discount_amount[$i];`

Comment: Yes I know, did you try my code? or you solved your problem?

Comment: yes i solved it, btw ty for your answer appreciate it!

Comment: i just remove the `[$i]` but when i store it with different amount of discount, in my database it will become the same discount as the last discount i store, this make problem again hoho